# Free exam builder with randomization of answers?

Tags: windows, open-source

I am searching for a free exam bulider software (Windows). The tool should also randomize the orders of the answers every time. So e.g.:

What is 5+1?

a) 5

b) 6

c) 9

d) 10

Next time when I start the test and do the training again the order should be different so e.g.

a) 9

b) 10

c) 6

d) 5

I want to create my own questions with this tool (approx. 100-120 multiple choice questions, but always only one answer is correct).

It would be great if the feature of adding pictures and figures to the questions is included.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is very old but maybe it would be useful for someone: you can always leverage online tools that work in a browser. There are couple of them, the one that I co-founded is [Testportal](https://www.testportal.net).

Comment: Welcome to [softwarerecs.se]! Please note that you need to explicitly state it's your own website; see the [Help Center](/help/promotion).

Comment: Sure, sorry for that, I not only use this app but I'm also a co-founder of this website. Home my answer will be useful!